# I can not fix the error XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I get the error / warning, but why so guys? and how to fix it, already the 3rd day can not cope with this error
Thats my error:

> jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.0:25 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the
>   main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the
>   end user's experience. For more help, check
>   https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

this is my `index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>


    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:link outcome="create" value="Insert a new diver"></h:link>

        <h:form  id="myForm">
                <p:dataTable   value="#{diverController.lst}" var="d"  scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500" style="width:800px;margin-left: auto;">
                <p:column headerText="Id" >
                    #{d.id}
                </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name" >
                    #{d.name}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Num">
                    #{d.num}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Status">
                   #{d.status}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Lat">
                   #{d.lat}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Lot">
                   #{d.lot}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Action">
                    <h:commandLink value ="Remove"
                                   action="#{diverController.remove(d)}"
                                   onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure')"></h:commandLink>||
                  <h:commandLink value="Edit"
                       action="#{diverController.edit(d)}"></h:commandLink>

                </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Check"  >
                        <p:commandButton id="mButn" class="Bzazaza" ></p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            <p:poll update="myForm" interval="10" ></p:poll>
            </h:form>

   <h:outputScript library="js" name="example.js"></h:outputScript>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Really need your help Thank you all

Comment: You have a script that is doing a synchronous XHR somewhere.

Comment: I know nothing about JSF or PrimeFaces but a quick Google search suggests that `h:commandLink` is most probably the culprit.

Comment: Where do you get the warning? In the browser, IDE, compiler?  Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @Jan error give me in a brouwser

Comment: "Deprecated" must not mean it isn't working. Synchronous javascript-requests can freeze the browser, is that your problem? The deprecated-message may have nothing to do with your problem, what is your exact problem?

Comment: @Gunnar dier friend Hi.My only problems this warrning message

Comment: I see. Primefaces should not contain synchronous js requests, so what is "example.js"? Try to remove the line and look if the error is still there. When example.js is the problem, it may contain "sync" or "async", and "sync" is bad for javascript requests. The problem is, that "some javascript" in your page contains a "synchronous" javascript request which means the request blocks the browser until it's finished (while an asynchronous request runs in the background).

Comment: Gunnar hav alternative method for table ?rich faces or omnifaces ?